# How to test the statistical significance of the difference between two ARPPUs?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ab-test

I have run an A/B test on the ARPPU (Average return per paying user) of two versions of a checkout page and hence I now have two ARPPUs, say x and y. The question is whether or not the difference between x and y is large enough to call it statistically significant. As I did the test via Google Analytics I do not have the raw data generating the two ARPPUs and hence the t-test and the Mann-Whitney U test are not feasible. What to do?

Comment: What data do you have? only the ARPPU's for the two variants? Can you segment it? filter it?

Comment: Yes, I only have the two ARPPUs. What do you mean by "Can you segment/filter it?"?

Comment: Im not sure if GA lets you segment/filter a/b test results. I.E looking at results for a specific segment/filter of traffic.

Comment: Why is this relevant at all? My aim is to compare group A's ARPPU with group B's ARPPU.

Comment: In order to get statistical significance you need some knowledge of the distribution between two variants. One way getting this knowledge is looking at dividing the samples into different groups -  hence segmentation.